# Command that writes to both stdout and stderr

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

We're doing workshops for internships where we explain the Bash. One topic is redirection, because it's quite important.

So far we explained `>` and `2>` independent from each other. Our examples are

```
echo Hello world
echo Hello world > file.txt
let x=1/0
let x=1/0 2> file2.txt
```

For programmers with an understanding of the concepts of `stdout` and `strerr`, that's not a problem.

However, for interns, the only effect in both cases is: the output is gone and was redirected into a file.

What I'm looking for is a command that produces both, regular output (`stdout`) and error output (`stderr`). That way we can use `>` to redirect only a part of the output, `2>` to redirect the other part or both to get 2 files.

The command should be rather simple and not involve too much preparation. The more preparation, the more likely that they will get something wrong.

Comment: Considering the file handles 0, 1, 2 are references to `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, wouldn't it be better just to explain those to them? A short walk through the basic concepts, "everything is a file", "to communicate with a file, you need a file handle", "the first three file handles are special" etc. shouldn't take that long and would, in my estimation, be more effective than just teaching your interns cryptic numbers without them grokking the background.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: We already and still explain it, but we get questions like "why can't we create a directory with `touch` if everything is a file?", "why do I need `rmdir` instead of `rm` to remove a directory, if a directory is a file as well?", "Why can't I use `chmod +d` to make a file a directory?" Actually we're discussing about the removal of that explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't avoid those questions, I'd welcome and forster them. Questions like this are signs that the concepts are starting to sink in. Just answer them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use something like

```
ls file not-a-file
```

where `file` exists in the current directory and `not-a-file` doesn't. Obviously you could substitute `ls` for any other simple command that takes filename arguments.